# setTimeout and copying button value to clipboard

Tags: javascript, object, null, settimeout, execcommand

I have a button, and I'd like to copy its value to the clipboard after the mouse has hovered over it for one second using just javascript, *not jQuery* if this can be avoided.

I have two problems with this code:

1. The setTimeout doesn't work--the alert occurs immediately without waiting one second, and
2. I get a "TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'document.getElementById(obj).value')" error

```js
function getButtonValue(obj) {
  document.getElementById(obj).value.execCommand("copy");
  alert("\"" + obj.value + "\" has been copied to the clipboard.");
} // function getid(obj)
```

```html
<input type="button" id="button2" value="bite me" onmouseover="setTimeout(getButtonValue(this), 1000);" />
```

Comment: the (this) is out of scope when the function runs

Comment: `getButtonValue` is expecting an ID (a string), not an object. `document.getElementById(obj)` takes a _string_ as argument, not an object.

Comment: You are executing the function right away....

Comment: Also, `.value.execCommand` does not exist. It is supposed to be `document.execCommand()` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand

Comment: And doubt execCommand is going to work without the user actually clicking something

Comment: Lots of wishful thinking here :/

Answer (score 2):

You are calling the method instead of assigning it to settimeout

here is how you would do it

```js
   function getButtonValue(obj) {
obj.focus();
obj.select();
const result = document.execCommand('copy');
if (result === 'unsuccessful' || result == false) {
console.log('Failed to copy text.');
}    
} // function getid(obj)
```

```html
<input type="button" id="button2" value="bite me" onmouseover="setTimeout(()=> getButtonValue(this), 1000);" />
```

Comment: OBS  `navigator.clipboard.writeText(obj.value)` will work if you have permission

Comment: See my version for a correct implementation of the promise based writeText

Comment: I know the right way but I did this as an example. The problem he has is with settimeout. And even with your implementation you well get permission problem in stack overflow.

Comment: Yours give console errors because you are not handling the promise. I do net get errors even when I have permission problems because I do catch the error

Comment: I really appreciate everyone's help, but Dreamweaver doesn't seem to like "}).then(permissionStatus => {" and possibly, in particular, "permissionStatus =>" in mplungjan's code.  Can anyone tell me what might the problem with this line of code?

Comment: I have updated my answer and used `document.execCommand('copy');` but there is a limit as `navigator.permissions` is much better to use. read here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Interact_with_the_clipboard

Answer (score 1):

If you get permissions you can do this - idea from other answer which was not implemented correctly

https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2018/03/clipboardapi

```js
var tId = "";

navigator.permissions.query({
  name: 'clipboard-read'
}).then(permissionStatus => {
  // Will be 'granted', 'denied' or 'prompt':
  console.log(permissionStatus.state);

  // Listen for changes to the permission state
  permissionStatus.onchange = () => {
    console.log(permissionStatus.state);
  };
})

document.getElementById("button2").addEventListener("mouseover", function(e) {
  var val = this.value;
  setTimeout(function() {
    navigator.clipboard.writeText(val)
      .then(() => console.log(val + " copied"))
      .catch(err => {
      // This can happen if the user denies clipboard permissions:
      console.error('Could not copy text: ', err);
    });
  }, 1000)
})

document.getElementById("button2").addEventListener("mouseout", function() {
  clearTimeout(tId);
});
```

```html
<input type="button" id="button2" value="bite me" />
```

Comment: Is there possibly a problem with:

Comment: I really appreciate everyone's help, but Dreamweaver doesn't seem to like "}).then(permissionStatus => {" and possibly, in particular, "permissionStatus =>" in mplungjan's code. Can anyone tell me what might the problem with this line of code?